# CSS/HTML/JS: Make element overflow regardless of ancestors overflow style (even if ancestor is absolute positioned)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, overflow

I see plenty of questions on this topic, but the solutions never work for ancestors that are absolutely positioned.

For instance, in:

```
<div id='page'>
     <div id='container' style="position:absolute; Overflow=hidden;">
          <img  style="position:absolute"  src=.../>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want the image to ignore the 'container's overflow. But since the container is absolutely positioned, the normal hacks don't seem to work (such as making the container relative). Is there a setting or creative work around to solve this? Thanks!

For context, i'm making a chrome extension that inserts an image on top of existing images on the page, but the inserted images often get clipped by any overflow styles of the parents (I know i can insert them outside the parent with the overflow style, thats my work around, but it introduces a lot of other problems).

Comment: Not sure what "hacks" you are referring to. There might be some specific situations where what you said achieves the desired result - but there is no general "ignore that overflow was supposed to be hidden" hack or switch or property. IMHO your best bet _is_ to position elements relative to the whole page.

Comment: @CBroe Was afraid of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='page'>
    <div id='container' style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
        <img style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; pointer-events: none;" src="..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation**

We added the z-index: 1; Navigate to the  element. This visually positions the image above its parent container (#container). You can adjust the z-index value as needed based on the desired stacking order.

We added pointer-events: none; Navigate to the  element. This ensures that the image doesn’t capture any mouse comments, and allows for interaction with objects below. Therefore, the image will not prevent the overflow of the parent object.

Using these CSS properties, the image will visually overlap its parent container while respecting the container's bulk settings, overcoming the problem of cropping an embedded image usage This option should work fine for your Chrome extension.

Comment: Appreciate it, but I just tried this out and it doesn't work :/  Img is still cut-off. Seems to only work when the container div is not absolute or relative.

Comment: So, at the end what you want to achieve will you please elaborate so, I can help you or assist you with this more.

Comment: I'd like to Img to not follow the container div's overflow setting (not be clipped by it), while allowing siblings to be clipped.

Comment: I don't think so, It would be possible like this because if the image is in div then it will always follow the div property there is no way to change it like this you have to change the container property. And you don't want to change the container property as a whole you can pass with to div class as an dynamic variable